Fatal error: defs.h: No such file or directory When using gcc to compile .c file
Using Openairinterface5g Open source software and am trying to compile one of the .c files using gcc - I keep on getting a very similar 'Fatal error' message which revolves around some sort of header file not being found. The problem text within the .c file I am trying to compile looks like this...
#include "defs.h" 

and gives an error message which reads something like
Fatal error: "defs.h": No such file or directory. Compilation terminated.
The fix I opted for was to go into the .c file I was compiling and set the pathway of the defs.h file so that gcc can find it. This works and solves the initial problem, but then a new error message appears, almost identical in wording except this time there is another .h file that gcc cannot find. This loop goes on and on and on and no matter how many times I direct the path I get the same problem.
On my 30th .h file I started to question the efficiency of this process and I get the feeling there is a better way to do this, so I wondered if anyone has any ideas. As far as I am aware I have build the 5G OAI software as per their tutorials but part of me wonders if they (or I) am missing something?
Any help is appreciated!

For a one-time job, you probably want to add the root dir containing the header files to the list of directories to be searched while includeing by passing it with the -I option to the gcc command: gcc -I /path/to/headers/ [...]

... see also Options for Directory Search in the gcc documentation. How exactly you do that beyond the case-by-case basis mentioned by @kos depends on the build system that you are using (i.e. you could add it to a Makefile, or pass it via the CFLAGS environment variable etc.)

@kos What would I do if there are multiple header directories with multiple paths? Should I take this approach but take the path to the highest common directory? i.e. gcc -I /path/to/openairinterface5g ?

@steeldriver, I hoped the open source developers had already added them to the makefile, unfortunately when I try to run the makefile I get the same error with the headers. I had a feeling I had missed some dependencies but I have triple checked and cannot see that I have.

I'm very foggy on the (little) I've done in C, including the the root path should suffice? But truth be told, I don't really remember how that works. But as steeldriver said, if you're using a makefile, you should probably instruct the makefile to look into those paths. I'd say wait for steeldriver to come back at this as I'm sure he'd be way more helpful than I could be, all I remember is that for simple cases you can pass the -I switch.

Openairinterface5g looks to be a large complex project that uses high level build tools (cmake, ninja) to manage its components - so "trying to compile one of the .c files using gcc" is likely to be complicated and frustrating. IMHO there's really not enough specific detailed information in your question to make it answerable as it stands.
